# Problemas com JUnit

Tags: java, testes, junit

estou tentando executar alguns testes numa pequena aplicação para estudos de JAX-RS. O Seguinte erro é mostrado quanto tento executar um caso de teste para simular um GET

```
org.junit.vintage.engine.support.UniqueIdReader 
lambda$apply$1
ADVERTÊNCIA: Could not read unique ID for Description; 
using display name instead: 
deveInserirUmAutor(br.com.sabium.test.AutorTest)
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: fUniqueId
```

O Engraçado é que meu colega de trabalho tem o mesmo projeto, com os mesmos jars, também lhe é apresentado os mesmos erros, porém o Junit passa os testes e os dados são persistidos no Banco de Dados. Algúem poderia me ajudar?

Aqui está o nosso arquivo de Testes: 
`

```
package br.com.sabium.test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import br.com.sabium.projeto.model.Autor;

public class AutorTest {
    private Client client;
    WebTarget target;
@Before
public void before() {
    this.client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/AvaliacaoTest/api");
}

@Test
public void deveBuscarUmAutor() {
    Autor autor = target.path("/autor/1").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(Autor.class);
    assertEquals("Thiago", autor.getNome());
}

@Test
public void deveInserirUmAutor() {
    Autor autor = new Autor("Rodrigo", 20);
    Response output = target.path("/autor/").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(Entity.entity(autor, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    System.out.println(output.getStatus());
    assertEquals(201, output.getStatus());
}

@Test
public void deveAtualizarUmAutor() {
    Autor autor = target.path("/autor/1").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(Autor.class);
    autor.setNome("Matheus da Silva");
    autor.setIdade(17);
    Response output = target.path("/autor/1/nome").request().put(Entity.entity(autor, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    System.out.println(output.getStatus());
    assertEquals(200, output.getStatus());
}

@Test
public void deveExcluirUmAutor() {
    Response output = target.path("/autor/10").request().delete();
    assertEquals(204, output.getStatus());
}
}
```

Comment: Qual versão do JUnit você está utilizando?

Comment: Olá Bruno! Estou usando o Junit 5.4